# why does MS C++ add this code to assembly?

Tags: c++, inline-assembly

i have some code(inline assembly).

```
void NativeLoop()
{
    int m;
    __asm
    {
        PUSH ECX
        PUSH EDX
        MOV  ECX, 100000000
NEXTLOOP:
        MOV  EDX, ECX
        AND  EDX, 0X7FFFFFFF
        MOV  DWORD PTR m, EDX
        DEC  ECX
        JNZ  NEXTLOOP
        POP  EDX
        POP  ECX
    }
}
```

MS C++ Automagicaly adds these codes(marked with **) to my procedure.
Why?
how to avoid it?

```
  **push        ebp  
  **mov         ebp,esp 
  **push        ecx  
  push        ecx  
  push        edx  
  mov         ecx,5F5E100h 
NEXTLOOP:
  mov         edx,ecx 
  and         edx,7FFFFFFFh 
  mov         dword ptr m,edx 
  dec         ecx  
  jnz         NEXTLOOP
  pop         edx  
  pop         ecx  
  **mov         esp,ebp 
  **pop         ebp  
  **ret
```

Comment: BTW, you are copying values into the `m` variable, but not doing anything with it.  Is this an error?

Comment: @Thomas Matthews:no it is not an error.it is for performance testing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is the standard function entry and exit code.  It establishes and tears down the stack frame.  If you don't want it you can use __declspec(naked).  Don't forget to include the RET if you do.

However, your snippet relies on a valid stack frame, your "m" variable requires it.  It is addressed at [ebp-10].  Without the preamble, the ebp register won't be set correctly and you'll corrupt the stack frame of the caller.

Comment: It's okay, he's not using the stack frame.  No function arguments, no local variables.

Comment: Huh? And what do you think his `m` is if not a local variable? If fact, his reference to `dword ptr m` will be translated into a `ebp`-based memory access, which is why the code inserted by the compiler is absolutely necessary.

Comment: note that even when there are no arguments, in most cases you'll mutate registers, and then you should know if your calling convention will leave the registers in a fine state, of if you have to write save/restore code by hand.

Answer (score 5):

It's maintaining the call stack.  If you defined the function as

```
int NativeLoop() { }
```

You would see the same assembly.

Comment: maybe because David's function is of type int

Comment: You probably saw something with eax, such as xor eax, eax if you said "return 0;" for the return value. This is because eax is the return value register and an xor of identical values results in zero.

Comment: It was xor eax, eax.(I think,bad memory)

Answer (score 5):

I remember that you can `__declspec(naked)` in MSVC++, meaning that you have to take care of the stack yourself, that means you must save every register you clobber, and restore it.

There is no the-one-rule to do that properly, as it depends on calling convention. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions .

Sidenote: In gcc, you explitly state to the compiler what you will drive invalid, so that gcc will output more optimal save/restore/stackframe-code, if any. In MSVC, asm is mostly a blackbox to the compiler, for which it will often/always the worst.

See http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#ss5.3 , gcc inline asm syntax is more ugly, but effectively more effective.

Comment: 99.9% of the time the compiler is going to generate better ASM than you in any case, and it's probably a good idea to not use ASM in normal code. Perhaps this is why MSVCC doesn't even bother looking at ASM code sections.

Comment: Of course. But in systems programming (not in my case, btw), you often need (inline) assembler, and then it's good when the compiler can optimize even that. But then, MSVC++ is anyways a wrong choice, as it doesn't even support amd64 targets (i.e. you'll have to write pure assembly and hook this up to your program)

Answer (score 4):

```
  **push        ebp  ;save EBP register
  **mov         ebp,esp  ;Save the stackframe
  **push        ecx  ; So that the variable `m` has an address
;...
  **mov         esp,ebp ;restore the stack frame to it's original address
  **pop         ebp   ;restore EBP register
  **ret ;return from function call
```

Comment: `push ecx` is its way of making `m` addressable. The standard requires that all non-reference, non-type identifiers (IIRC) have an address. So, VC is putting `m` (stored in `ecx`) onto the stack, where it will have a memory address (which is then referenced in the assembly). It's not being "dumb."

Comment: I wasn't sure.. my C/assembly mixing is a bit rusty.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do a search on C++ calling conventions, you'll understand better what the compiler is doing.